# Define msghdr length in sendmsg and recvmsg (unix sockets)

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to send and receive messages through unix domain sockets, using **sendmsg** and **recvmsg** functions (C language).

The process is very simple:

- the server sends a string to the client using **sendmsg** (must use **struct msghdr**);
- the string is passed as argument in main (argv[1]);
- the client receives the string using **recvmsg**;
- the client prints the string to the stdout.

I have the following problem:

1 - When the server sends the string "test":

```
$ ./server test
```

2 - The client prints it correctly:

```
$ ./client
print data received > test
```

But,

1- When the string is bigger (> 7 chars), like "hello_world":

```
$ ./server hello_world
```

2 - The client prints strange characters (as if there was no '\0'):

```
$ ./client
print data received > hello_woh?!#
```

Is the problem related to the length of the message?

How can I define the length of the message in order to print it correctly?

EDIT: Server source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/usocket"

int send_msg_to_client(int socketfd, char* data) {

  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  int s;

  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = NULL;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  iov.iov_base = data;
  // replace sizeof(data) by strlen(data)+1
  iov.iov_len = strlen(data)+1;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;

  printf("msg: %s\n", (char *) iov.iov_base);

  s = sendmsg(socketfd, &msg, 0);

  if(s < 0){
    perror("sendmsg");
    return 0;
  }

  return s;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        if (argc != 2) {
          printf("Usage: $ %s <data>\n",argv[0]);
          return 0;
        }

    int s, s2, len, slen;
    socklen_t t;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char* data = argv[1];

    printf("print data: %s\n",data);

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    unlink(local.sun_path);

    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");

    t = sizeof(remote);
    if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected.\n");

    slen = send_msg_to_client(s2, data);

    if(slen < 0)
        perror("send");

    printf("sent data length: %d\n", slen);

    close(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Client source code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/usocket"
#define MAX 100

int recv_msg_from_server(int socketfd, char data[MAX]) {

  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  int s;

  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = NULL;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  iov.iov_base = data;
  //replace sizeof(data) by MAX
  iov.iov_len = MAX;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;


  s = recvmsg(socketfd, &msg, 0);

  if(s < 0){
    perror("recvmsg");
    return 0;
  }

  return s;
}


int main(void)
{
    int s, len, slen;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char data[MAX];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

    printf("Trying to connect...\n");

    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(remote));

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }

    printf("Connected.\n");

    slen = recv_msg_from_server(s, data);

    if (slen < 0) {
        perror("recvmsg");
    }

    //data[MAX] = '\0';
    printf("print data received > %s\n", data);

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first glance, looks like you are setting the length of payload (`iov.iov_len`) to `sizeof(data)` which is `sizeof(char*)`. Guessing that you are running it on a 64-bit machine, this size is 8 bytes, which explains why it did work for shorter strings.

You probably want to make it `strlen(data) + 1`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the explanation!

I tried strlen(data)+1 but the client prints the first 2 characters (is considering strlen(data) as 1??). Then I replaced this with iov.iov_len = MAX; in the client side and it works. But, is not the best solution.

Comment: Why don't you print the `iov_len` bytes pointed to by `iov_base` right before sending to see what is being sent? Assuming data points to a valid NUL-terminated string longer than 1, your `iov_len` is supposed to be larger than that.

Comment: Hmm... How can it be 4 (for string "test")? It's got to be 5. Try debugging it to see what you get in iov_len.

Comment: On server side, I have no problems. I'm printing the `char* data`  and `strlen(data)` before the `sendmsg` function. And printing `msg.msg_iov->iov_base` and `strlen(msg.msg_iov->iov_base)` after the `sendmsg` function. The values are ok! But, on client side, when I print `char data[]` and `strlen(data)` before the `recvmsg` function, I get a strange character and the value 1 to the strlen. After the `recvmsg` function I get the correct values.

Comment: Sorry Alexander, the other comment was very confused, so I removed it. `strlen("test")` gives 4 and not 5.